# Preventing mathematica from evaluating "Sort" function, except in the case of numerical values

Tags: sorting, numerical-value

Say I want to sort the eigenvalues E1, E2, and E3 using "Greater" as following:

```
{EA, EB} = Sort[{Chop[E1], Chop[E2], Chop[E3]}, Greater][[{1, 2}]];
```

But I want to prevent the sorting unless the values of E1, E2, and E3 are numerical. 
How can I do this?

Comment: It works fine for me. What didn't I understand?
lst = {3, Indeterminate, 7., Red, 11/13, "Text", Sqrt[2]}
Sort[lst]
gives:
{11/13, 3, 7., Sqrt[2], "Text", Indeterminate, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}

Comment: I think "Sort" the order gives arbitrary order unless the values are numerical, so I want to disable "Sort" in order for the eigenvalues to take numerical values. @uC-Harry

Comment: After a lot of try and error to learn about Sort I have an idea for you. Use
SortBy[lst, If[NumericQ[#], N[#], -\[Infinity]] &] which works for my list from above in the way: {11/13, Sqrt[2], 3, 7., "Text", Indeterminate, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}